# SWIG generate Java wrapper private method

Tags: java, swig

Given the following SWIG interface file:

```
%module abc
%{
    extern int my_function(int number);
%}

extern int my_function(int number);
```

It will generate the following public static Java wrapper method:

```
public static int my_function(int number)
{
    return abcJNI.my_function(number);
}
```

How can one have this Java method being generated as private such as this:

```
private static int my_function(int number)
{
    return abcJNI.my_function(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by including the following line in the SWIG interface file:

```
%javamethodmodifiers my_function(int) "private";
```